# Python IDLE fails to run

Tags: python, process, command, python-idle

Some time ago I was making a script in python which included lots of command prompt syntaxes...
I accidentally created an infinite loop and it screwed things up. Every time I try to test any script through IDLE it keeps opening and closing command prompt windows until I manually terminate process from taskmgr... Running scripts in command line works fine...

So how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing IDLE?

Comment: LOL. Sounds like the time I did "sudo apt-get remove python". It was fun seeing ubuntu crash more and more with every button I touched until it was finally bricked... Reinstall your python.

Comment: +1 for @RickyA, and also you should look into using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper in future to prevent things like this happening again.